# Ubuntu Software center half download issue

Tags: ubuntu

I was trying to download a software "Pycharm". It was half downloaded then I accidentally closed Ubuntu's Software Center. Now when I am trying to install it again its showing me this error shown in the screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddvRO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try [installing from Terminal](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installation-guide.html):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to open Terminal.
- Type `sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic` for the Classic version.

See the above URL, [Linuxize](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pycharm-on-ubuntu-18-04/) or [FOSS](https://itsfoss.com/install-pycharm-ubuntu/) for other ways to install or reinstall.